# Excel VBA: Get formula to dynamically determine range based on number of days in month

Tags: vba, excel

I have built a monthly report that lays out values for each unit by day-pictured below).
[image: picture of worksheet].

In the report, I am only concerned with Tuesdays and whether or not the cell contains a value.  The goal is to fill in the rows of "Days Counted" and "Days Not Counted" (at the bottom of the worksheet). A day that was not counted (meaning that the intersection of the date and unit is blank) counts as not counted.

Now, through some help here on Stackoverflow, I have been able to use the following code to calculate the number of Tuesdays that were counted and the number of Tuesdays that were missed.  This works great if the month is 31 days. However, it only returns errors if the month is say, 30 days, or 28 days.  The real problem is the following equation:

```
ActiveCell.Offset([myRange], 0).FormulaArray = "=SUM((WEEKDAY(startDate:endDate)=3)*(R[-32]C:R[-2]C<>""""))"
```

I've been trying to get an offset function to work with defined names within the sum function but can't get it to work.  I don't know if this the best way to accomplish this--I'm open to suggestions on re-writing the whole thing.

I would be very grateful for any help on getting this to work so that it can correctly interpret a month with any number of days.

Important FYI: The module I am struggling with here is applied to several different worksheets (another module loops each worksheet through the module in question).  The first worksheet has the table (pictured above) starting on row ~6, whereas all of the other worksheets have the table start on row 1, which is why I am unable to use static references in the formulas.

Just in case it helps to see the whole module, it is included below:

```
Sub calculations()

Range("A100").End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value = "Days Counted"
ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Value = "Days Not Counted"
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.Name = "startDate"
While ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value <> Empty
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Wend
ActiveCell.Name = "endDate"
ActiveCell.Offset(10, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=endDate-startDate+1"
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "General"
ActiveCell.Name = "numDays"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Int((EndDate - StartDate + Weekday(StartDate - 3)) / 7)"
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "General"
ActiveCell.Name = "numTues"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=numDays+2"
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "General"
ActiveCell.Name = "myRange"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=numDays+3"
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "General"
ActiveCell.Name = "notCount"
'calculates number of days counted.  Must be entered as an Array Formula (Ctrl-Shft-Enter) if done manually.
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
    ActiveCell.Offset([myRange], 0).FormulaArray = "=SUM((WEEKDAY(startDate:endDate)=3)*(R[-32]C:R[-2]C<>""""))"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Wend

Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
    ActiveCell.Offset([notCount], 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=numTues-R[-1]C"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Have not fully digest your code, but perhaps you can use Names for all those sheets, and then a VBA to update the `RefersTo` range of these names. This makes your formulas easy to read, and manage one means all for a set of rules. Or even have the VBA to create Names and formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel macros are pretty cool, but excel itself is pretty cool too!

You can do this without any code by exploiting some built in excel functions and array formulas.

To enter an array formula (which returns an array of results rather than a single value) you type the formula as normal and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter. Don't type the curly brackets { }, excel puts them in automatically to show that it is an array formula.

To get the Tuesdays that have values use:

```
{=SUM((WEEKDAY($A$2:$A$32)=3)*SIGN(B$2:B$32))}
```

Which says - give me an array of the weekdays of the dates, compare them to 3 (giving an array of TRUE and FALSE), multiply this by the SIGN of the quantities (1 if >0, 0 if 0, -1 if <0) (giving an Array of 0's and 1's) and add them up.

To get the Tuesdays that don't have values use:

```
{=SUM((WEEKDAY($A$2:$A$32)=3)*1)-SUM((WEEKDAY($A$2:$A$32)=3)*SIGN(B$2:B$32))}
```

Which says - give me an array of the weekdays of the dates, compare them to 3 (giving an array of TRUE and FALSE), multiply this by 1 (giving an Array of 0's and 1's because you can't add up TRUE and FALSE) and add them up - This is all the Tuesdays. The second part is just the formula above.

This will work for any arbitrary list of dates and quantities - you don't need the whole month.

**Edit re determining the range**

```
=DAY(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,1)-1)
```

will give you the number of days in the month of the data in Cell A2

```
=OFFSET(A2,0,0,DAY(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,1)-1))
```

will give you the cells from A2 to A[last day of the month i.e. 28,29,30,31 as applicable)

```
=OFFSET(A2,0,1,DAY(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,1)-1))
```

will give you the range to the right of that, and

```
=OFFSET(A2,0,2,DAY(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,1)-1))
```

the next column and so on.

You can put these into named ranges -  a lot of people don't know that named ranges are just formulas so if you set up named ranges like

```
DayOfMonth =$A$2
Dates      =OFFSET(DayOfMonth,0,0,DAY(DATE(YEAR(DayOfMonth),MONTH(DayOfMonth)+1,1)-1))
```

then the first formula becomes

```
{=SUM((WEEKDAY(Dates)=3)*SIGN(OFFSET(Dates,0,1)))}
```

Comment: I like the formula route but that is what I am having trouble with.  Specificically, in your example, The range B$2:B$32 is only true for a month with 31 days.  If it is a month with say 30, the range is offset and returns an error with the way the sheet reformats (because the table in question doesn't start at row 1).  I have been able to get the first A2:A$32 range to calculate based on defined Names, but I can't seem to get the same thing to work for the sign range. Any idea how to get that range to determine what it should be?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA or array formulae, if you can add an indicator column for each of your "Unit" columns.

You can use the indicator column to perform your complex logic and assign a simple value to the result. Then your counting column only needs to count. Here's an example, using an indicator column on your Unit 1 data, and showing the dates as day names for clarity.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCzEv.png

It still works if there are less than 31 days in the month, and some of the date rows are blank.

If you're writing code to handle new worksheets that are being generated by some other process, then you could write code to create the indicator column and counting formulae, then do copy and paste values into the count result cells, then delete the indicator column.